# Windows 11 Snipping Tool: "This app can't open" error message

Tags: windows-11

Upgraded yesterday from *Win 10 Pro* to *Win 11 Pro*.
Since updating, the Windows Win+Shift+S to take a screenshot snippet doesn't work.
I even manually launched the app itself, clicked the [+New] option and was greeted with this popup:

[image: error]

I've tried the refresh option but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's being replaced with Snip & Sketch ever since Win10 launched; apparently they didn't commit for Win11...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Snip & Sketch is being renamed back to Snipping Tool, FYI (read more at https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-snipping-tool-mail-calendar-windows-11/). The article mentions "merging the two" but there isn't really any functionality in Snipping Tool that wasn't also in Snip & Sketch, so I view it as just "removing old Snipping Tool and renaming Snip & Sketch to take its place", personally.

Comment: @TylerH "is being" or "has been"? The non-committal language doesn't inspire confidence.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't know the status, and I don't have Windows 11, so I can't say for sure. But given that the update is a rolling one, like many of Windows' updates, I'd say both "has been" and "is being" are true. Some people have already received the update, others may not have received it yet. And I don't know if it will get pushed to Windows 10 or be kept Win-11-only.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Snip & Sketch **has** been renamed to Snipping Tool. The linked article was from **before** Windows was released in October.  Both the original version of Snipping Tool and Snip & Sketch on Windows 10 will still exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I've tried the refresh option but to no avail. Any ideas?

This is due to an expired certificate used to sign several built-in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications on Windows 11 version 21H2.

> Starting on November 1, 2021, some users might be unable to open or use certain built-in Windows apps or parts of some built-in apps. This is caused by an issue with a Microsoft digital certificate, which expired October 31, 2021.
>
> The following applications might be affected:
>
> - Snipping Tool
> - Accounts page and landing page in the Settings app (S mode only)
> - Touch Keyboard, Voice Typing, and Emoji Panel
> - Input Method Editor user interface (IME UI)
> - Getting started and Tips

The solution to this problem is to install the out of band update KB5008295  which was released on November 5th.

- Touch Keyboard, Voice Typing, and Emoji Panel
- Input Method Editor user interface (IME UI)
- Getting started and Tips
- Snipping Tool
- Accounts page and landing page in the Settings app (S mode only)

Source: [Snipping Tool and some built-in applications might not open or work as expected](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21h2#november-2021)

Comment: There is a newer patch available>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/november-5-2021-kb5008295-out-of-band-5540f171-846c-4af0-b363-29b6f02a8935

Answer (score 6):

I found this workaround at [techcommunity.microsoft.com](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/report-an-issue/snipping-tool-cannot-open-windows-11/m-p/2906268/page/14):

1. Open Settings app.
2. Navigate to Time & Language.
3. If the ‘Set time automatically option is switched on”, turn it off.
4. Select “Change” next to ‘Set date and time manually’.
5. Change the Date to October 31 or before.
6. Start the snipping tool.
7. After success, change it back to the latest date.

[image: strange_but_true]

Comment: [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21h2#november-2021) is the reason rolling the date of the system back works.

Comment: I'd imagine you should open the app before changing the time back, because otherwise this would be incredibly esoteric. And presumably this will only work until the app is closed (which since it's a UWP app wouldn't happen too often, but at the least when you restart).

Answer (score 0):

KB5008295, released on November 4th '21, resolves this issue. At this time it's available in Beta and Release Preview Channels (Windows Insider).

> We fixed a known issue that might prevent some users from opening or
> using certain built-in Windows apps or parts of some built-in apps.
> This issue occurs because of a Microsoft digital certificate that
> expired October 31, 2021. This issue might affect the following
> applications:
>
> - Snipping Tool
> - Touch Keyboard, Voice Typing, and Emoji
>   Panel
> - Input Method Editor user interface (IME UI)
> - Getting started and
>   Tips

https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/11/04/releasing-windows-11-kb5008295-to-beta-and-release-preview-channels/